# How to run form action and click event simultaneously on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having a form like this

```
<form name="test" action="action.php" method="get">
<input type="text" />

<input type="button" value="download"/></form>
```

I need a click event for download button. Eg. If i click download it should submit as action.php and run  `$('#button').click(function(){` also. How can I do it.

Comment: Why don’t you write the code to submit the form inside the click function?

Comment: Is that possible to submit without downloading ?

Comment: As OP said themselves in comments, this is not their actual question, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55607291/ is. So this here should be voted to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform the operation on 'download' button click then trigger the form submit using `trigger`

```js
$('.download').click(function(e){
alert('downloading!')             //Your Download Logic HERE
$(this).parent().trigger('submit')//Trigger Form SUBMIT ONCE THE OPERATION IS DONE

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="test" action="action.php" method="get">
<input type="text" />
<input type="button" value="download" class="download"></form>
```

Comment: I am sorry, its little unclear to me. My actual question is stackoverflow.com/questions/55607291/…. Can you please take a look

Comment: @Ansh first please confirm this question

Answer (score 1):

Firstly note that `<form>` elements are not self closing, so your current HTML is invalid; the `input` elements need to be *within* the form itself.

Once that is fixed you can `trigger()` a `submit` event on the parent form to the `#button` element, like this:

```js
$('#button').click(function() {
  console.log('Custom logic here...');
  $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
});

$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('Submitting form...');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="test" action="action.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit" value="search" />
  <input type="button" value="download" id="button" />
</form>
```

Comment: I guess that's not quite it, he wants a click event on the download button (`'#button'`) and in that event he wants to submit too

Comment: Yep, just realised. Editing it now.

Comment: But maybe you are right and he wants both actions when *submitting* or *dowloading*

Comment: I am sorry, its little unclear to me. My actual question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55607291/how-to-show-values-in-input-box-after-submit-button-click?noredirect=1#comment97912151_55607291. Can you please take a look

Answer (score 1):

You can simply submit your form by javascript, after clicking `download` button:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
...
    document.forms["myform"].submit();
```

Comment: I am sorry, its little unclear to me. My actual question is stackoverflow.com/questions/55607291/…. Can you please take a look